# Display image from database Codeigniter

Tags: php, image, codeigniter

i store profile images in database by adding this code to upload process

```
($config['upload_path'] = './img/photos/';
$data['img'] = $config['upload_path'].$image_data['file_name'];).
```

In my database there is img column that has such paths

`./img/photos/8f8eeb37d5fd82b7ba4cd16a356064ce.jpg`.

how can i display image in my view file? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

```
echo $image_data['file_name'];
```

see what you get then add missing path .

Answer (score 0):

Add this path with your `base_url()`. In your `view` file:

```
$url = base_url().$img;
<img src="<?=$url?>" />
```

You can also check your `URL` in browser before putting it in image tag.

Answer (score 0):

For more dynamic, I would suggest to change

```
'./img/photos/';
```

to

```
'img/photos/';
```

It would put your file in the same directory then your file path would be nicer "img/photos/8f8eeb37d5fd82b7ba4cd16a356064ce.jpg"

To display your image you could :

```
$url = base_url().$image_path; //http://domain.com/img/photos/8f8eeb37d5fd82b7ba4cd16a356064ce.jpg
<img src="<?php echo $url;?>"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

Do not store image with path in your database table.
Store only image name in your img column of the table.
For path, you can make one constant.
Form that constant, you can retrieve image from the path.